# Changing address on Passport for Indian Citizen?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

My parents will shift to a different address in Delhi in a few months. The old address/house will still be our property though. The residential address on my passport is for the old address.

Currently I am not residing in India though. Is it necessary for me to change the address on my current passport? If I choose to **not** do so right now and do it when my passport expires, will I run into problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** and **no**.  The address on the passport is a convenience, acting as proof of address and so the passport can (in theory, anyway) be returned to you if you lose it.  It does not have to be up to date.

The [Passport India FAQ](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable) does not explicitly state this, but a number of the questions like Q65 say things like *"Proof of Present Address (if address is different from the one mentioned on passport)",* which clearly implies that it's OK to have an old address in your passport.

Comment: Since technically, we still own the property at the previous address, would it be acceptable if I use my passport as a proof of address with the old address?

Comment: Why not?  If somebody wants a document saying X, and you have a document saying X, then all is good.